# Adblock plus doesn't work in Waterfox

Tags: firefox, browser, adblock

I'm trying to use Waterfox, a 64 bit version of FireFox. I installed Adblock plus and it's enabled but it doesn't do anything. The ads appear and when I right click on them there's no option to block them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adblock Plus: When upgrading Adblock Plus disables itself. To re-enable it, go to

- Add-Ons
- Disable
- Enable and then refresh the page you're on

[Source](http://waterfoxproject.org/)

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know why this happens, for example is it a bug in Waterfox or Adblock plus?

Comment: I'm sorry, all I know is ithere is a compatability issue - as to where the fault is, I don' know.